# How to iterate over Array or nil ([]?) type in Ballerina?

Tags: arrays, loops, ballerina

I have a variable of type Array or nil([]?) and I am trying to iterate over each element.

```
mysql:Client db = check new (host, user, password, database, port);
stream<Brewery, sql:Error?> rez = db->query(query);
Brewery[]? brewery = check from Brewery brwr in rez select brwr;
```

Brewery[]? does not look like it can be iterated.
What should I change in above code to iterate over each element in `Brewery[]? brewery`

Additionally, is there a way to take only the top 5 items in the statement,
`Brewery[]? brewery = check from Brewery brwr in rez select brwr;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to narrow the type of the variable down to an array type before using it as an array. For example, you can use the `is` check in an `if-else` statement.

```
if brewery is () {
    // Handle the nil scenario.
} else {
    // The type of `brewery` is narrowed to `Brewery[]` here,
    // so it can be used in a `foreach` statement.
    foreach Brewery item in brewery {
        
    }
}
```

As for the second question, you can use the `limit` clause to limit the number of values.

```
Brewery[]? brewery = check from Brewery brwr in rez limit 5 select brwr;
```

Please refer to the documentation for [limit-clause](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/limit-clause/).